# like photo from graph api explorer

Tags: facebook-graph-api, photo, explorer

I am trying to like a friends photo for some preliminary research on a website feature and I'm finding strangeness in the graph api explorer. I have the publish stream option checked. But when I set the dropdown to POST and set the URL to IMAGE_ID/likes, it reports:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Trying Too Often: You are attempting this too often.  Please try again later.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 368
    }
}
```

and then I am immediately logged out of facebook. Would a kind soul be willing to try to like a friend's photo through the Graph API explorer and see if it works?

Comment: I'm getting two results, neither of them result in a "Like". I either get an empty `result` object (and no Like) or the same error you're getting.

Comment: I think this might be related: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/220044948118289

Comment: And maybe this: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/254250354686066?browse=search_500dbcc327f139c47748285

Comment: Same issue. Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, pass the URL and I'll see what happens.

Tested it with a pic from a friend of mine, worked like charm...

Comment: Just to confirm, you checked this o the graph explorer? http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/